# Amazon Cognito Oauth2 Native App : Best practice

Tags: amazon-web-services, oauth-2.0, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito

I am developing backend API's for a native app. This backend service(developed using java/springboot) is deployed on AWS. For Securing the backend API's I am planning to use Oauth2 (Authorization Code grant Flow with PKCE).

I am trying to achieve this through Amazon API Gateway and Cognito User Pool. This is what I have done so far.

1. I have created Cognito user pool
2. Add an app client(app client id/secret)
3. Configured Domain and Resource Server
4. Configured App Client Settings with Authorization code grant as the OAuth flow
5. Created a user with default password and also changed password.
6. I have setup Amazon API(with resource mapping to my backend) with this cognito user pool as Authorizer.

With these setup my workflow is like this

A. Call `/oauth2/authorize` endpoint of my domain with response_type as code and also pass all necessary information like client id, callbackurl, code_challenge_method, code_challenge etc. This redirects to `/login` page. I login with the username/password created in step 5 above. This will return me a code.
B. Call `/oauth2/token` with the code returned from previous step and all the other necessary details including code_verifier. This will return me access_token(refresh_token, id_token)
C. Use this token to call the Amazon API Gateway endpoint.

All this is working fine. But I have a couple of questions.

1. Do I create an app client (step 2 above) Every time a user downloads the app from playstore. Is app client related to per user or per app?
2. Do I need to create a new user(step 5 above) everytime a user downloads the app and want to use it? I have my own customer registration/login process in my app/backend implemented. I do not want Amazon to handle this. But I need atleast one user in cognito user pool to get the code(Step A). Not sure how this should be handled.
3. Currently I am using dummy callback url. As this is a mandatory field. How can I handle this in my native app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You need to create 2 app clients (with a secret for backend application) and without secret for the native app. `secret` for a server application to call Cognito API in some cases. => **Not every time, only 2 app clients **. AWS has a limitation. Ref:https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/limits.html
2. The best practice is users create an account by themself. Then log in and get credentials from the backend. Depend on the credential, you will enable or disable functions in the native app.
3. As the AWS document, you can set callback URI as `myapp://`. But I still use dummy callback. I get Token from HTTP headers (which return from Cognito)

Comment: Thanks for tips(+1) couple of follow up questions
1. Why 2 app clients? can you elaborate. I did not understand. What do you meant by without secret for native app.
2. How should user create an account on AWS coginito pool by themselves?

Comment: 1 => First: you need at least one app client to work with Cognito. Second: App client with the secret help you easy to create auth token => Please refer links https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=820844 and https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/token-endpoint.html

Comment: 2 => Idea is your backend will call Cognito API to check/add user/ login user. But the user should enter login information by themselves. Refer: https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/cognito-idp.html#CognitoIdentityProvider.Client.sign_up

Comment: Regarding point 2. But how do we authenticate the first call to backend where we check/add/login user. Because at this point user is not created and hence he/she cannot get a code. Hence outh flow is not completed

Comment: In API Gateway, we set a route for `get code` to None Auth => the user can get code without credential

Comment: Thanks for the info. One last question. I have my own sign-up and login screen in the native app. Does that mean when user signs up or login to the app, I have to create user / login the user using Aws cognito SDK?  Do you have any code samples for this

Comment: Yes.. feel free to contact me via skype: `ahuhyeu` if you want

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206041/discussion-between-pvpkiran-and-tuanva).

Answer (score 2):

To add to TuanVA's very good points:

2. Users need to be saved to Cognito as well as your back end. [My write up](https://authguidance.com/2017/10/02/user-data/) may help you to understand options, which can vary depending on where the security ownership lies.
3. The most standard option is to use a private uri scheme based callback such as com.mycompany.myapp:/callback

If it helps I have an [Android sample app you can quickly run against Cognito](https://authguidance.com/2019/09/13/android-code-sample-overview/).

My sample is pretty detailed though, and deals with integrating AppAuth libraries, so may be more complicated than you need.

Comment: Will look into the write up. Thanks. I can create users in cognito using Aws SDK from backend as u suggested along with saving in my backend.. But how shud the first call from app to backend be authenticated because at this point user is not there in cognito , hence the call cannot get code and oauth flow cannot be completed

Comment: You should set auth to None, then user can call your backend without token

Comment: Thanks @Gary do you have any Java code samples for user sign-up and login using Aws cognito SDK

Comment: Not exactly. My recommendation would be to use a standards based solution for login via Authorization Code Flow, and to use the SDK only for adding users. Maybe if you can explain requirements around how you want to create users (eg self sign up or via an administrator UI) I can advise more closely. Also what tech are you using for the web app (server side with Spring Boot maybe?)

Comment: Generally in Java [these libraries](https://connect2id.com/products/nimbus-oauth-openid-connect-sdk) are very good - though you may prefer Spring Boot's built in stuff.

Comment: sorry for the late reply. Currently in my mobile native app(without authentication). I havea register button with which user can enter details and the app calls the backend /register endpoint to create user in the database. And then there is /login endooint which is called when user tries logging in. This is one of the basic feature that the app has. Once logged in user can do many things. Now the point is, how do I secure this /register and all the other backend endpoints. As you suggested. I can create a user both in my database and cognito. But this means user has to login twice when loggin

Comment: once for my app and once in aws login page to get authorization code. can the second login be avoided? Another point is, how can I secure /register endpoint. because at this point we do not have the user in cognito so we cannot generate authorization code and hence cannot implement oauth flow. How do i prevent some malicious app calling /register endpoint a million times