# Implementing Oauth2 Authorization Code Grant flow Manually

Tags: java, spring-boot, oauth-2.0

I am planning to implement Oauth2 Authorization code grant flow (With PKCE) Manually. My question is partly related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59733220/amazon-cognito-oauth2-native-app-best-practice). I am using Java, Springboot.

I want to secure my backend API's with Oauth. These api's are called by the native app. Most of the Oauth implementations for Authorization code grant require user interaction. I was wondering if its possible to avoid this. Since my application runs on a native app, I do not want user to be redirected to a browser for authentication. My app has a Register/Login functionality.

I am planning to implement a filter, where the logic would look something similar to this

```
if(uri contains authorize){
    get all details from request
    generate a uuid and store details in db with ttl
    return uuid as code.
}

else if(uri contains token){
    get all details from request
    extract code from request and check for validity in database.
    if(code valid) {
       generate a JWT with access_token with ttl and refresh_token
       return JWT
    }
}

else{
    check if JWT is present and valid
    if valid proceed
}
```

I will also have a logic for refresh token. I want to know

1. Are there any security flaws in doing like this
2. Is there any other alternative way to achieve Authorization Code grant flow without user interaction.
3. With respect to PKCE. Using PKCE mitigates the threat of having the authorization code intercepted, by not creating/storing the client secret. But what stops the user from sending a request to the authorize endpoint with his/her own code challenge? How safe is the client id in native app?

Answer (score 2):

First of all

### **Do not, i repeat do NOT ever try to implement some form of custom security by yourself**.

That is one of the worst things you can do. Security is complicated, and often requires multiple teams to implement. Thats why we have standard libraries for it. **Use spring security.**

Answers to your question:

1. Security flaws are everywhere. Security is so much more then just the small snippet of code you have posted. oauth2 is a standard, with exact rules as to what and how you verify and check things. So my quick answer is yes, you are not following the standard. So yes, it is insecure. Use spring security.
2. No, when you say user interaction, i have no idea what you are talking about. You need to follow the defined flow, and if you chose to automate the flow or not, it is up to you. Describe what it is you **ACTUALLY** want to do.
3. ClientIds or anything for that matter is never safe in any app. It all depends on the level of security you are looking for. If we are talking enterprise security you usually store all secrets in the backend and you implement some sort of BFF, for your frontend app that holds all the client secrets, and also performs the exchanges. The only thing that gets stored in the client are different type of secure cookies.

So if you choose that you actual native app is making the exchanges, or some sort of proxy service is up to you. But no, no secret is ever safe in any client.

Comment: 2. The general flow with Authorization Code grant is. First the client(in my case native app) will hit /authorize endpoint with client_id and other details. On doing this the call is redirected to a login screen where user has to type in username and password. Only after this the code is generated and redirected to an uri. This is what I meant by user interaction. Is it possible to generate the authorization code without user entering username and password.

Comment: 3. I am not talking of client secret. I will not store client secret in the app  Instead I will use PKCE. I want to know about client_id. This needs to be in the app right?

Comment: why do you want to do this without the username and password? in that case you can drop the entire authentication. Why do you need oauth2 if the user are not going to authenticate themselves, it makes no sense

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I have a native app .. For simplicity let's assume it has register and login feature. I have the backend endpoints for register and login which is called by the native app. Now, how do we secure this communication  between app and backend API. I thought if using authorization code grant , but it requires redirection to some URL where user logs in. But with which credentials? Can you suggest what is the best approach here.

Comment: how do you mean secure it, secure it from what? you have a login feature, users login with username and password using oauth2 and get issued a token. The authenticated user then uses the app to perform actions, and passing the token. I think you need to read up, and fully explain what it is you want to do, because to me it feels like you have no idea.

Comment: "users login through username and password" agreed. How do we secure the register / sign up call? There is difference between oauth login and my app login . These are two separate things. Authorization Code grant flow requires user to login to generate a code. How do we generate this code when  /register endpoint is  called.  Thanks for the feedback nonetheless

Comment: i have no idea what the "register/signup" call is, what type of application, you are talking about a native application? native to what, mobile, arduino, IoT, raspberry PI, iPad. If we are talking mobile then you use PKCE during the oauth2 authentication of the users. But if you just want to protect from malicious application registering themselves, you are probably out of luck.

Comment: It is a mobile app. "But if you just want to protect from malicious application registering themselves, you are probably out of luck" ----> This is exactly my point